# Affect of not using const while overloading * operator

Tags: c++

I am just trying few codes to understand overloading << operator, most explanations are quite understandable but I am facing some issue with the use of const keyword.
Below code is giving me a compilation error, saying no match for operand Fraction,Fraction)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Fraction
{
private:
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;
public :
    Fraction(int val1, int val2):m_numerator(val1),m_denominator(val2){};
    void print()
    {
        cout<<m_numerator<<"/"<<m_denominator<<endl;
    }
    friend Fraction operator*(Fraction &f1,Fraction &f2);
    friend Fraction operator*(Fraction &f1, int value);
    friend Fraction operator*(int value,Fraction &f1);
};

Fraction operator*(Fraction &f1,Fraction &f2)
{
    return Fraction(f1.m_numerator * f2.m_numerator, f1.m_denominator * f2.m_denominator);
}

Fraction operator*(Fraction &f1, int value)
{
    return Fraction(f1.m_numerator * value, f1.m_denominator);
}

Fraction operator*(int value,Fraction &f1)
{
    return Fraction(f1.m_numerator * value, f1.m_denominator);
}

int main()
{
Fraction f1(2, 5);
f1.print();

Fraction f2(3, 8);
f2.print();

Fraction f3 = f1 * f2;
f3.print();

Fraction f4 = f1 * 2;
f4.print();

Fraction f5 = 2 * f2;
f5.print();

Fraction f6 = Fraction(1, 2) * Fraction(2, 3) * Fraction(3, 4);
f6.print();
}
```

The problem with the above code is that there is no const preceded with the Fraction object while using it as a function parameter, the below code is working fine:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Fraction
{
private:
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;
public :
    Fraction(int val1, int val2):m_numerator(val1),m_denominator(val2){};
    void print()
    {
        cout<<m_numerator<<"/"<<m_denominator<<endl;
    }
    friend Fraction operator*(const Fraction &f1,const Fraction &f2);
    friend Fraction operator*(const Fraction &f1, int value);
    friend Fraction operator*(int value,const Fraction &f1);
};

Fraction operator*(const Fraction &f1,const Fraction &f2)
{
    return Fraction(f1.m_numerator * f2.m_numerator, f1.m_denominator * f2.m_denominator);
}

Fraction operator*(const Fraction &f1, int value)
{
    return Fraction(f1.m_numerator * value, f1.m_denominator);
}

Fraction operator*(int value,const Fraction &f1)
{
    return Fraction(f1.m_numerator * value, f1.m_denominator);
}

int main()
{
Fraction f1(2, 5);
f1.print();

Fraction f2(3, 8);
f2.print();

Fraction f3 = f1 * f2;
f3.print();

Fraction f4 = f1 * 2;
f4.print();

Fraction f5 = 2 * f2;
f5.print();

Fraction f6 = Fraction(1, 2) * Fraction(2, 3) * Fraction(3, 4);
f6.print();
}
```

why const is playing this much important role here, there can be scenario wherein I do not need const keyword, how I am going to deal with those cases.

PS: The error is in the line specifically:
Fraction f6 = Fraction(1, 2) * Fraction(2, 3) * Fraction(3, 4);

Any explanation would be a great help.

Comment: It was a mistake, I have just edit the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line that fails is this one:

```
Fraction f6 = Fraction(1, 2) * Fraction(2, 3) * Fraction(3, 4);
```

The reason is that anonymous temporaries cannot be modified.  This is a language feature meant to protect you from yourself, because usually if you want to modify something you want to use the result.  So your non-modifying operators need to take their arguments either by const-ref or by value.

Comment: I think they *can* be modified (one of the reasons people used to return const values). They just can't be bound to non-const lvalue references.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to get a hold of `const` correctness. All of your functions tell the compiler that that they can modify the passed in parameters.

In particular this means that this:

```
Fraction f6 = Fraction(1, 2) * Fraction(2, 3) * Fraction(3, 4);
```

which the compiler has to generate code something like this:

```
Fraction const tmp1 = Fraction(1, 2);
Fraction const tmp2 = Fraction(2, 3);
Fraction const tmp3 = operator*(tmp1, tmp2);
Fraction const tmp4 = Fraction(3, 4);
Fraction f6 = operator*(tmp3, tmp4);
```

Note that compiler produced temporaries are not actually `const`, but you cannot bind to them using a non-const reference (i.e. you should use `const &` rather than just `&` in the function prototype, or not use a reference at all), partly because if you write code that alters a temporary that subsequently disappears, it's pretty meaningless, and almost undoubtedly not what you meant to do. (Historical note: In at least one version of a fortran IV compiler - where everything is passed by non const reference - it was possible to alter the value of the numerical constant 1 because the language had no concept of constness or temporary variables, leading to much confusion).

But none of your arithmetic operators take `const` references (despite not actually altering their parameters), the compiler can't find an appropriate method to use and hence errors that statement.

Incidentally, you don't have an operator<< overload, and nowhere in that code sample would you actually be using it if you had one.

Note also your `print` method isn't `const` and it should be or you wont' be able to use it on a `const` Fraction object.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Can you please explain this a bit "but you can only bind to them using a non-const reference"....

Comment: sorry, typo earlier on. Cleaned up and expanded

Comment: Thanks...it helped..!!